# Weird behaviour regarding complex numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x, complex-numbers

I'm currently writing a Mandelbrot program in python. In one implementation, I used python's complex number type. In the other, I implemented complex numbers as two separate numbers (I think I have an error there). I don't understand why the two programs output a different-looking result since they should both do the same thing (unless I have some stupid error in my code). Could someone tell me why this is happening (and possibly what I did wrong), and how I can fix this?

This is my code:

```
size = 40

for y in range(size):
    for x in range(size*2):
        c = complex(x / (size / 2) - 2, y / (size / 4) - 2)
        z = complex(0, 0)

        i = 0;
        while i < 100:
            z = z**2 + c
            if abs(z) > 2:
                break
            i+=1
        if i == 100:
            print("#", end="")
        elif i > 10:
            print(".", end="")
        else:
            print(" ", end="")
    print()

#########################

size = 40

for y in range(size):
    for x in range(size*2):
        cx = x / (size / 2) - 2
        cy = y / (size / 4) - 2
        zx = 0
        zy = 0

        i = 0
        while i < 100:
            zx = (zx * zx - zy * zy) + cx
            zy = (2 * zx * zy) + cy
            if zx * zx + zy * zy > 4:
                break
            i+=1
        if i == 100:
            print("#", end="")
        elif i > 10:
            print(".", end="")
        else:
            print(" ", end="")
    print()
```

The upper Implementation prints this:

```
                                    .
                                        #
                                     ..
                                   .####.
                                   .####.      .
                            ..#..##########......
                           ...#################.
               .           .###################. .
                ......    .#####################.
                .#######..######################.
            ....#########.######################
##############################################.
            ....#########.######################
                .#######..######################.
                ......    .#####################.
               .           .###################. .
                           ...#################.
                            ..#..##########......
                                   .####.      .
                                   .####.
                                     ..
                                        #
                                    .
```

And the lower one prints this:

```
                                        # .    .
                                     ..#####.. .   ..
                                 ############# ... .
                  .            #################.
                 .  #.        #################### #
                 .#### .   .#######################
                 #######..###########################.
                ##################################.
              #######################################
             #####################################
##############################################.
             #####################################
              #######################################
                ##################################.
                 #######..###########################.
                 .#### .   .#######################
                 .  #.        #################### #
                  .            #################.
                                 ############# ... .
                                     ..#####.. .   ..
```

Comment: are you using Python 2 or 3?

Comment: I am using `python3`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga When I run with pyhton2 it looks even worse.

Comment: Definitely it shouldn't work. The `/` operator changed between Python 2 and 3, in Python 2 it was integer division, in Python 3, it defaults to true division and `//` is the operator for integer division. I was just asking because often people do not realize this was the behavior in Python 2.

Comment: The issue is essentially the same as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42047993/4996248). It is interesting to see what the bug looks like with better graphics

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mutated zx and used it in your zy calculation. You need to store your new value for zx elsewhere temporarily so you can properly calculate zy. Something like this:

```
temp = (zx * zx - zy * zy) + cx                                        
zy = (2 * zx * zy) + cy                                                
zx = temp
```

Or more elegantly:

```
zx, zy = (zx * zx - zy * zy) + cx, (2 * zx * zy) + cy
```

Answer (score -2):

This is a guess, but are you using python 2? The values at the bottom plot seem to be making a very approximate graph of mandelbrot, but slightly skewed-looking. I am willing to bet that you are using python 2, where the division operator `/` only does integer division.

If this is the case, either use python 3 or add this to the beginning of your code:

```
from __future__ import division
```

Comment: You have posted this answer several minutes after OP clarified that they are using Python 3

Comment: Check the comments under my question. I already stated that I am using `python3`.