# Commas to optimize Python Variables

Tags: python

I had a question on how python code can be formatted.

```
 (q, a), b = divmod(b, a), a
        y0, y1 = y1, y0 - q * y1
```

For something like above, how do the commas to demonstrate variables work? Can someone show how this code would look without the use of commas between y0 and y1, or the (q,a)? I know it must be some sort of way to optimize the code.

Comment: It can be read as `y0 = y1` and `y1 = y0 - q * y1` and assignment happens simultaneously, without the need for an additional temporary variable

Comment: It's a convenience, not an optimization.

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists

Comment: sometimes to use without comma you would have to use extra variable ie. `temp = ...`

Comment: It's not entirely convenience, the assignment is done "at the same time" (to a certain point)

Comment: Thank you, all your answers were helpful.

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42052645/4996248) featured an interesting bug which was debugged by replacing two successive assignments by a single assignment with commas.

Answer (score 1):

Commas at assigments are used for *tuple creation on the right side and unpacking on the left side*, e.g:

```
x, y = 1, 3
```

Which is functionally equivalent to

```
x = 1
y = 3
```

Or for example *list unpacking*, e.g:

```
example_list = [1, 4, 5]
x, y, z = example_list
```

Which is functionally equivalent to:

```
x = example_list[0]
y = example_list[1]
z = example_list[2]
```

So your code without "commas" would be:

```
(q, a) = divmod(b, a) # unpacking
b = a
old_y0 = y0
y0 = y1
y1 = old_y0 - q * y1
```

The reason for this is mostly `convenience` and not optimization of the code.

Comment: your last example is wrong because you update `y0 = y1` and later `y1 = y0 - q * y1` uses new value in `y0` but it has to use old value. You have to keep `old_y0 = y0` and late `y1 = old_y0 - q * y1`

Comment: "chained assignment" is the wrong term. On the right side of the equal sign you create a tuple and on the left side it's called "tuple unpacking".

Comment: The final code is not exactly equivalent, as looking at the byte code using `dis.dis` would show, though it is functionally equivalent.